# How to fix BootStrap5 Button Spacing?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

So, i have been trying to create a actual decent navigation bar with buttons, but the spacing doesn't really work out with it.

(I don't really know if its because of Python Flask, but i put that as a tag anyway)

This is what happends when i run my code:
https://ibb.co/nC7cX7s

Here is my code in Python Flask:

```
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
      <img src="/static/img/AdiAvi.png" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
      AdiAvi
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a {% if homePage %} class="nav-link active" {% endif %} {% if dashboardPage %} class="nav-link active" {% endif %} class="nav-link"  href="/">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a {% if contactPage %} class="nav-link active" {% endif %} class="nav-link" href="/contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
        {% if baseTemplate %}
        <button type="button" id="loginButton" class="ml-2 btn btn-danger navbar-btn">
          Login
      </button>
        {% endif %}
        {% if baseTemplate %}
        <button type="button" id="registerTrigger" class="ml-2 btn btn-primary navbar-btn">
            Register
        </button>
        {% endif %}
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

And here is my code when i run my application:

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark" style="background-color: #333;">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
      <img src="/static/img/AdiAvi.png" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
      AdiAvi
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a  class="nav-link active"   class="nav-link"  href="/">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a  class="nav-link" href="/contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
        
        <button type="button" id="loginButton" class="ml-2 btn btn-danger navbar-btn">
          Login
      </button>
        
        
        <button type="button" id="registerTrigger" class="ml-2 btn btn-primary navbar-btn">
            Register
        </button>
        
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

As you can see, i tried adding the `class="ml-2 btn btn-danger navbar-btn"` to each of the buttons, expecting for it to move to a right a little bit, but instead nothing happened. It just stayed the exact same.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

I also tried using other posts answers for this problem, but at the end it still hasn't really worked out for me

Comment: hi, you might be able to use some of these classes https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/spacing/

Comment: Great Answer! But the problem is i tried various bootstrap spacing methods in the classes like ML and MS, but they all still don't work. Its a very weird situation. I don't really know what the problem is with it.

Comment: use ms-2 instead

Comment: There is no `ml-2` class in bootstrap. Because of RTL texts Bootstrap use ms - margin start (margin left) and me - margin-end (margin-right). For non-RTL text `start` means left, `end` means right, but for RTL `start` means right and `end` left. `ms-2` is a proper class.